# Ubuntu appears twice in UEFI boot options

Tags: uefi

I'm a noob at Ubuntu, but when I enter in the UEFI boot menu, Ubuntu appears twice (like this: Ubuntu (P0 : ST750LM022 HN-M750MBB).

I installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode as my only operating system, removing Win 7.I, and when I finished creating the partitions, the installer prompted me to create another partition, UEFI boot or something like this, so I had to create that one as well.

*Is this bad?*

Here's a screen shot of `gparted`:
[image: gparted screen shot]

Comment: I'm on 8.1 and when I get to that screen the first option is something like BootLoader and then there are 2 ubuntu entries. I always just used the first. Never went in other to see if would just boot the same or fail. That is if we're taking about same screen. I have to hit f9, this screen comes up. I select second option that is ubuntu, then I finally get to grub where I can again select ubuntu. If I don't do this, grub never loads and Windows boots. Pretty sure were taking about same thing. It like bootloader, 2 listing of Ubuntu and then some UEFI option

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of the `gparted` window and drop me a note @Fabby?

Comment: @Fabby i can't post images because i need a higher reputation.I don't know if it helps you,but i have 4 partitions.One is a linux swap partition(46 gb),a / logical partiton(100 gb),another logical partiton /home (600gb) and a boot/efi partition in fat32 format(148mb).

Comment: //i.stack.imgur.com/xMS6x.png @Fabby

Comment: You can remove obsolete entries with `efibootmgr` ([How do I remove “Ubuntu” in the bios boot menu? (UEFI)](http://askubuntu.com/q/63610/40581)). But better leave it as it is unless you want to fiddle with UEFI and possibly discover firmware bugs that leave you puzzled and waste time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not *bad*...

It's *not beautiful* neither, but it's **not bad**.  Knowing that UEFI gives lots of people trouble, *ignore* it!  Don't try to fix a working system!

Comment: Okay.A big "thank you" man.It's nice to see that the Ubuntu community is so friendly;)